# Background-Position animation issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, scrollmagic

I am a designer turning developer, working on learning parallax. I made this test, and it works great on Chrome, but not in FireFox or IE. Any suggestions?

I am using ScrollMagic, which is built on GSAP.

Here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    // build tween
    var tween = TweenMax.fromTo("#clouds2", 5, 
            {"background-position": "50% 0px"},
            {"background-position": "50% 2500px"}
        );

    // build scene
    var scene = new ScrollScene({triggerElement: "#container", duration: 3000})
                    .setTween(tween)
                    .addTo(controller);

    // show indicators (requires debug extension)
    scene.addIndicators();
});
```

http://joeyellisdesign.com/testingspace/parallaxtest/test/

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'addIndicators'` in IE's console. Press F12 to get to the development tools

Comment: easily remedied by including the debug js as well as scrollmagic

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a TweenMax issue.
The reason is you shouldn't use "background-position", but "backgroundPosition"

See here: http://greensock.com/forums/topic/8394-firefox-animating-background-position/

For future help follow this guide: https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a bug with TweenMax. I don't know the solution, but I found a work-around.

I tested the following solution on Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

You have to add both "background-position" and "backgroundPosition"

This code should work:

```js
var tween = TweenMax.fromTo("#clouds2", 5, 
            {"background-position": "50% 0px",
            "backgroundPosition": "50% 0px"},
            {"background-position": "50% 2500px",
            "backgroundPosition": "50% 2500px"}
        );
```

Hopefully TweenMax fixes the bug because I don't know if there is any downside to including both.